# Two-Way bind Single Object Observable

Tags: angular

I want to perform two-way data binding on an element in Angular 4 but I'm having problems. Can anyone provide some direction?

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Load } from '../services/model/load';
import { LoadService } from '../services/api/load.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-storeedit',
  templateUrl: './storeedit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./storeedit.component.css']
})
export class StoreeditComponent implements OnInit {
  load: Observable<Load>;
  private sub: any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private loadService: LoadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      // Require ID
      var loadId : number = +params['id'];
      this.fetchLoad(loadId);
    })
  }

  fetchLoad(loadid : number): void {
    this.load = this.loadService.apiLoadByIdGet(loadid);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    //Called once, before the instance is destroyed.
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
   <div>
        Cartons: {{(load | async)?.cartons}} <input type="range" [(ngModel)]="(load | async)?.cartons.value" max="1000" value="{{(load | async)?.cartons}}">     
    </div>
```

I want changes made on the input slider to reflect in the model.
This line:  `Cartons: {{(load | async)?.cartons}}`

Shows the current value, but when the slider is adjusted, the value does not seem to change.

I have tried also using `ngModelChange` with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a side note, I think that unsubscribe is not necessary, it goes automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you cannot have pipes there so you have to split the two-way binding to two one-way bindings:

```
<input type="range" [ngModel]="(load | async)?.cartoons.value" (ngModelChange)="loadValueChange($event)">
```

Now, in your component make a `loadValueChange(newValue)` method that will update the value on your observable.

Comment: How do I update the observable? Since it is of type Observable<Load> I don't have access to the properties on Load.

Comment: Well, that's what you can do in `loadValuechange()` method. It should probably notify `loadService`, as that's the source of "load" observable: `this.load = this.loadService.apiLoadByIdGet(loadid);`. Now, maybe you need to save right away and emit the new value. Maybe you just set a new property "isSaved", then mark it in the UI that the user also needs to click "save" to save the new value. This is really dependent on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

out of interest is this.load visible to the component or should it be:

```
  fetchLoad= (loadid : number): void =>{
  this.load = this.loadService.apiLoadByIdGet(loadid);
  }
```